# Does Remdesivir really go bad after reconstitution with sterile water?

Tags: medications, drug-administration

I was recently looking at how long can Remdesivir be stored in its different forms.

I came up across several articles provided by the [FDA](https://www.fda.gov/media/137566/download) and [Gilead Sciences](https://www.gilead.com/-/media/files/pdfs/remdesivir/eua-fact-sheet-for-hcps.pdf) and [others](https://www.chkd.org/uploadedFiles/Documents/COVID-19/remdesivir%20CHKD%20guideline%204-3.pdf).

What caught my eye was the fact that after you reconstitute Remdesivir with sterile water you cannot store it at all! The manual and articles provided by numerous sources all say the same thing. they clearly state that you should use the reconstituted solution right away, meaning combine it with a NaCl serum. The serum then can be stored for up to 48 hours inside the fridge (no more than that).

Of course, I am not a medical professional and will not advise anyone to do anything other than what has been said inside the manual, however, I'm still curious as to how accurate this information is. specifically:

1. Will Remdisivir reconstituted with sterile water inside its vial "**Go bad**" when stored in the refrigerator for a week or two?
2. If so, **how** does it do so?
3. What can you do to store reconstituted drug (e.g: Remdesivir) vials for later use? (e.g: wanting to use the drug for a longer period but at a lower daily dose)

Comment: Regarding question 1, I don't understand why you doubt the product literature. Do you imagine they just make this stuff up? Question 3 is off topic because it calls for advice on how to intentionally misuse a drug. Question 2 is okay but it can probably only be answered by chemists who work for the manufacturer and would be a better fit on the Chemistry exchange.

Comment: @CareyGregory 1. I believe that they probably have a certain standard for antivirals with a large safety margin and do not specifically test this drug per se, so their information might not be accurate. 3. Why misuse? Maybe I want to administer Remdesivir to a cat because of FIP and since the vials are for human use I cannot administer the complete vial in a single dose? and since the drug is rather expensive I cannot throw out the remaining drug. You can have a legit reason to store a reconstituted vial, from research on animals to therapeutic use for cats and dogs.

Comment: @CareyGregory Btw, If you doubt the "Legit" use of Remdesivir for FIP treatment maybe you should checkout the following article by the university of UCDAVIS: https://ccah.vetmed.ucdavis.edu/sites/g/files/dgvnsk4586/files/inline-files/Summary%20of%20GS-441524%20treatment%20v5.pdf

Comment: Asking us how to use a drug is medical advice, which is strictly off topic here even if it's advice for a cat. The reasons for the storage limit are explained in the drug's emergency use authorization.

Comment: @CareyGregory The question then arises, where does one ask about this question? whether one is a doctor or not? Maybe if medical information was widely available people would stop believing in ineffective treatments such as vitamin C and whatnot for COVID and other diseases alike. Or maybe some people would stop believing in anti-vax movements. and medical science would progress at a faster pace.

Comment: In the end, my cat's vet just put the vial in the fridge for about 5 days, contrary to what the manual said. and the cat got better after a week of treatment with Remdesivir which we have to continue. However, I will still stay clueless as to why no other doctor out of several dozen doctors would do as such, and would not believe the fact that Remdesivir does indeed work for FIP. Just because doctors and medical professionals don't believe in sharing information, because of the fear of "misuse". Misuse that, happens all the time with none-prescription drugs and chemicals.

Comment: Nobody is against sharing information. I found the reason for the storage limitation in less than a minute with a simple google search. This is why this site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. So once you know that the reason for the storage limitation is that the drug doesn't contain preservatives, which makes pathogen growth in stored solutions a risk, you could formulate a better question. What you have here is basically an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I wanted to make sure whether solution Y (which is not doing anything and just storing the vial) has actually worked. I did know about contamination, that's why you should use a sterile syringe and sterile water to make the reconstituted solution. This is true for all injectable drugs and is "common sense". However since a needle has entered the vial, the hole that the needle has left behind can cause contamination in the future. This has made me doubt whether the storage method used by my vet is the right thing to do. thus me asking the question

Comment: Maybe it would be better if he would tape a cotton ball smeared with alcohol on top of the vial?! Which again I doubt would be better than just plainly storing it. Maybe store it inside a fridge that has been sterilized with alcohol? Or maybe there is some kind of a preservative that can be added to the vial for long-term storage for this specific case? I understand that the FDA and Gilead have not thought about this. Otherwise there would be small vials specifically for animals. but that doesn't mean that the treatment should be unavailable or avoided, hence me asking this question.

Comment: Your vet is the one to ask about this since they're the one doing it and they presumably have the knowledge and experience to do it safely. You could edit this question to make it about pathogen growth in stored vials, but any form of question asking how to go about storing a vaccine contrary to manufacturer's instructions would be closed as personal medical advice.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now that I was in an XY Problem. However, I don't know how I should have managed to come out of it without the help of someone else. I managed to find [two](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7050144/) [papers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3813212/) dealing with this issue.